# How to calculate the average of the same pixel on 10 pictures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I want to get the average of the same pixel (150,220) for each picture of these 10 pictures.

How to do it?

Each picture is the same size.

for example:

img1[220,150]=[1,2,3]

img2[220,150]=[2,3,4]

……

img9[220,150]=[9,10,11]

img10[220,150]=[10,11,12]

avg_value = [(1+2+……+9+10)/10,(2+3+……+10+11)/10,(3+4+……+11+12)/10]

My code:

```
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread( r'E:/0001.jpg' )
img2 = cv2.imread( r'E:/0002.jpg' )
img3 = cv2.imread( r'E:/0003.jpg' )
img4 = cv2.imread( r'E:/0004.jpg' )
img5 = cv2.imread( r'E:/0005.jpg' )
img6 = cv2.imread( r'E:/0006.jpg' )
img7 = cv2.imread( r'E:/0007.jpg' )
img8 = cv2.imread( r'E:/0008.jpg' )
img9 = cv2.imread( r'E:/0009.jpg' )
img10 = cv2.imread( r'E:/0010.jpg' )

img_array = [img1,img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7,img8,img9,img10]
```

Comment: I don't see what exactly your problem is. Do you know how to read the value of any pixel in any of those images? Because if so, why can't you just read all the pixel values you need in the same manner and calculate the average from those?

Comment: (img1+img2+...+img10)/10 if the data type is double precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we can compute the mean pixel value of a specific pixel in a set of images using `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

names = [r'E:/0001.jpg', 
         r'E:/0002.jpg',
         r'E:/0003.jpg',
         r'E:/0004.jpg',
         r'E:/0005.jpg',
         r'E:/0006.jpg',
         r'E:/0007.jpg',
         r'E:/0008.jpg',
         r'E:/0009.jpg',
         r'E:/0010.jpg'];


#Read all the images
images = [cv2.imread(i) for i in names];

#Get that specific pixel of all the images (making a 2D array). Exclude non-existing images
vals = np.array([im[220,150,:] for im in images if im is not None]);

#Compute mean along the first axis of 2D array
m = np.mean(vals, axis=0);

print(m)
```

Tested with **Python 3.4** and **OpenCV 3.4** on Ubuntu **14.04**.